# A program that creates an account

Tags: python

What I want the program to do is to ask the user to first enter age. if user is above 18 then the next step is to ask the user if he/she has an account(right now the reply should be no). Then the user should be asked to enter username and password which is then stored in a dictionary which already contains a few values and the final step is to print out the values of the dictionary.

The code below shows in detail what I have tried.

```
#Dictionary containing user info
userdata = {"therealchacha":1234, "swampout":1111, "indiejones":2222,}
#input asking for age
actAge = int(input("Enter age: "))
#function that asks for age 
def ObtainAge(age):
    if age < 18:
        return "Access not granted"
    else:
        return "Access granted"
print(ObtainAge(actAge))
#input to take in account info
accountDetails = input("Do you have an account? Type Y for yes and N for 
no.")
accountDetails = accountDetails.lower()
#function that creates account
def accountAccess(acc):
    if acc == "N":
        return "Create account"
        usrName = input("Create username: ")
        passWord = input("Create passWord: ")
        userdata.update({usrName:passWord})
        return userdata
    else:
        return "site in progress"
print(accountAccess(accountDetails))
```

I didn't get any error message. The main issue seems to be that fact that the program is not noticing the "If" statement and giving output as "Site in progress" which is only supposed to happen when the user inputs that he has an existing account.

Comment: `accountDetails = accountDetails.lower()`, so you set `accountDetails` to _lowercase_ then check if they are `== 'N'` (_uppercase_) in your function. How could `if acc == "N":` ever be true?

Comment: One issue I see unrelated to your specific question: you have two `return` statements inside the `if True` portion of your function. What happens when a function hits a return?

Answer (score 1):

```py
#Dictionary containing user info
userdata = {"therealchacha":1234, "swampout":1111, "indiejones":2222,}
#input asking for age
actAge = int(input("Enter age: "))
#function that asks for age 
def ObtainAge(age):
    if age < 18:
        return "Access not granted"
    else:
        return "Access granted"
print(ObtainAge(actAge))
#input to take in account info
accountDetails = input("Do you have an account? Type Y for yes and N for 
no.")

#accountDetails = accountDetails.lower()
#function that creates account

def accountAccess(acc):
    if acc == "N":
        print("Create account")
        usrName = input("Create username: ")
        passWord = input("Create passWord: ")
        userdata.update({usrName:passWord})
        return userdata
    else:
        return "site in progress"
print(accountAccess(accountDetails))
```

You are returning immediately when the program enters into if condition and also `N` get converted to `n` when it does `accountDetails = accountDetails.lower()` (commented that part).

I have added a `print()` to display the account creation process.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, the print instead of return worked.

Answer (score -2):

```
#Dictionary containing user info
userdata = {"therealchacha":1234, "swampout":1111, "indiejones":2222,}
#input asking for age
actAge = int(input("Enter age: "))
#function that asks for age 
def ObtainAge(age):
    if age < 18:
        return "Access not granted"
    else:
        return "Access granted"
print(ObtainAge(actAge))
#input to take in account info
accountDetails = input("Do you have an account? Type Y for yes and N for no.")
accountDetails = accountDetails
#function that creates account
def accountAccess(acc):
    if acc == "N":
        return "Create account"
        usrName = input("Create username: ")
        passWord = input("Create passWord: ")
        userdata.update({usrName:passWord})
        return userdata
    else:
        return "site in progress"
print(accountAccess(accountDetails))
```

Edited to fix problems the OP never asked about and make the task make some semblance of sense. Here is what your code should probably look like if I am guessing what you mean to do correctly.

```
class user_setup():
    def __init__(self, existing_user_data):

        self.user_data = existing_user_data
        self.hasAcc = False
        self.access = False
        self.accinit = False

    def _account_init(self):
        age = int(input('Enter your age: '))
        if age < 18:
            print ('You are too young to setup an account')
        else:
            self.access = True

        if self.access:
            haveAccount = input('Do you have an account? Type Y for yes and N for no: ').upper()
            if haveAccount != 'N' and haveAccount != 'Y':
                print('\nYou must specify Y for yes or N for no')
                self._account_init()

            self.accinit = True
            if haveAccount == 'Y':
                self.hasAcc = True
            else:
                self.hasAcc = False

    def setup_account(self):
        if not self.accinit:
            self._account_init()
        if self.hasAcc and self.access:
            print ('Site in Progress')
        elif self.access and not self.hasAcc:
            print ('Please follow the following prompts to create an account\n')
            usrName = input('Please enter a username: ')
            passWord = input('\nPlease choose a password: ')
            verify = input('\nPlease verify your password: ')

            if passWord != verify:
                print ('passwords did not match\n')
                self.setup_account()  
            else:
                self.user_data[usrName] = passWord
                return None


#Dictionary containing user info
userdata = {"therealchacha":1234, "swampout":1111, "indiejones":2222,}

accounts = user_setup(userdata)

accounts.setup_account()
```

Comment: This partially worked. Now what is happening is that the program just ends with "create account". it further dose not ask for input.

Comment: @swampout it can't work because you put `return "Create account"`, which immediately breaks out of the function, so the indented lines of code underneath that never run. They also didn't put any explanation into what they had actually changed

Comment: @roganjosh, that's in the original code, not just this answer's code

Comment: @G.Anderson yeah, I realised after posting. Edited, thanks. But it really shows that minimal effort was put into the answer; it's not my downvote but I don't think it is of any use.

Comment: @Will.Evo Please remove the return statement and  I don't get why you have done this `accountDetails = accountDetails`?

Comment: My bad ,forgot to take that off.

Comment: I wasn't out to solve your entire programs problems, I was out to solve the problem you asked about, which was EXPLICITLY why the if statement wasn't returning True. I am not a mind reader, I don't know what your program is or isn't suppose to do. Why would I assume you have other problems in the code if I don't know what it is meant to do past the if statement.

Comment: @swampout see my answer revised to do all the work for you /s